# i want the domain of my client xyz.com to show the content of abc.com while in url it shows xyz.com (logo and branding to be set up on the fly)

Tags: php, redirect, dns, cname, domain-masking

I have a website that I have made with cms and branding control. But I don't want to create hosting plan for each domain and upload the same content and database for each domain.

First I want to redirect any domain to my website with authentication and then setup the index page branding and logo etc.

I have seen companies asking customers to Add the cname records in their websites and then after the authentication process of the domain, the site opens with branding like in zeerecharge.com and sahajrecharge.in (Both sites points to same IP/Server and content with CMS).

for example : Adding CNAME Records (from domain control panel).

---

For adding CNAME records first you have to login to your domain/web control panel under the Manage DNS/Add DNS/DNS Editor/DNS Zone (the exact terms may vary by host) and from there you have to add CNAME records to your domain/sub-domain.

Click CNAME Records and in the next screen, click Add CNAME Record

There you would find 3 fields:

Host Name: Here the domain name, for which you are adding the CNAME Record for, would be pre-filled (e.g. yourdomain.com). Now, if you wish to add a CNAME Record for sms.yourdomain.com, then you would have to put in ‘sms’ in the text box. If you wish to add CNAME Record for just yourdomainname.com, then you can leave this box blank.

Value: Here you have to select the second option (Fully qualified domain name) and put the CNAME value cloudserver7.com

TTL: This is the Time To Live for this Record, in seconds. Any Server which once queries this Record will query it again after this time interval. The ideal TTL is 86400, which is 1 day. It can not be set to less than 14400, i.e., 4 hours.

Click the Add Record button to submit your Record.

---

with this method the domain redirects to the entered URL but it changes the URL in the Address bar. I'm sure this is not the full process of doing what i want but I still don't have idea what I should do next.

Comment: ask your question at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Domain Masking' feature. It will show render xyz.com in address bar while showing the content of abc.com.

For more assistance, contact your hosting company. They can set you up.